# Complex Access Formula Logic

Tags: excel, ms-access, if-statement, ms-access-2010, formula

I am having some trouble getting some complex IF logic to work inside an MS Access query and am feeling fried at this point, so I am hoping a fresh pair of eyes can help me solve my issue.

The following screenshot I hope will help make my logic more clear.

[image]

My end result with the formula is to determine if a borrower (Borr) is out-of-date with submitted documents. In this case, I only care about the **(P)FS** and / or **IE** documents.

The conditions for being out-of-date are a bit complex and I will explain them below. *TRUE* equates to being out-of-date and *FALSE* to being compliant.

1. If the `NR` box is checked for `(P)FS` and `IE` Then *FALSE*
2. If the `NR` box is not checked for `(P)FS` And `IE` and the (P)FS`date is blank AND`IE` date is blank Then *TRUE*

This is easy enough, but now for the tricky part
*CYYY = current year, PYYY = prior year, PY2Y = 2 years ago*

1. If `(P)FS` or `IE` is required and If the current date is between 1/1/CYYY and 4/30/CYYYY and the Date in `(P)FS` or `IE` is between 10/1/PY2Y and 4/30/PYYY Then *FALSE* Else *TRUE*
2. If `(P)FS` or `IE` is required and If the current date is between 5/1/CYYY and 9/30/CYYYY and the Date in `(P)FS` or `IE` is less than 1 year old Then *FALSE* Else *TRUE*
3. Last thing to keep in mind is that as long as there is an up-to-date `(P)FS` or `IE` document, the result should be **FALSE**. They are both not required. It's either or.

This screenshot should help clarify the date formulas:

[image]

This is the last Access formula I have entered but still doesn't work. I also think I know why, but I am too fried with this to try to continue to solve for the moment:

```
    B1-FS-IE: IIf([annual_review].[prop_cd]<>"0056" And [nr_fs_b1]=True And 
[nr_ie_b1]=True,False,IIf(([nr_fs_b1]=False And IsNull([fs_b1])) And ([nr_ie_b1]=False 
And IsNull([ie_b1])),True,IIf(Month([fs_b1])>9 Or Month([fs_b1])<5 
And (Month(Date())<5 And Date()-[fs_b1]>576) Or (Month([fs_b1])>4
 And Month([fs_b1])<10 And Date()-[fs_b1]>=365) Or Month([ie_b1])>9 
Or Month([ie_b1])<5 And (Month(Date())<5 And Date()-[ie_b1]>576) 
Or (Month([ie_b1])>4 And Month([ie_b1])<10 And Date()-[ie_b1]>=365),True,False)))
```

Finally, I placed the `Excel` tag because if someone can work this out in Excel, I can translate to Access.

Comment: A formula like this is not only a nightmare to develop but also to maintain. I would put the logic into a public VBA function, and pass the relevant fields as parameters. There you can write readable code.

Comment: @Andre - Brilliant! I didn't even think about that. That would make it much easier to build, read, maintain! Thank you for the change in perspective I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need a proper method for calculating years - like this function:

```
Public Function Years( _
  ByVal datDate1 As Date, _
  ByVal datDate2 As Date, _
  Optional ByVal booLinear As Boolean) _
  As Integer

' Returns the difference in full years between datDate1 and datDate2.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   negative differences
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'   negative date/time values (prior to 1899-12-29)
'
' Optionally returns negative counts rounded down to provide a
' linear sequence of year counts.
' For a given datDate1, if datDate2 is decreased step wise one year from
' returning a positive count to returning a negative count, one or two
' occurrences of count zero will be returned.
' If booLinear is False, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0,  0, -1, -2
' If booLinear is True, the sequence will be:
'   3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3
'
' If booLinear is False, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results of same absolute Value, only the sign will change.
' This behaviour mimics that of Fix().
' If booLinear is True, reversing datDate1 and datDate2 will return
' results where the negative count is offset by -1.
' This behaviour mimics that of Int().

' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of years to dates of Feb. 29.
' when the resulting year is a common year.
'
' 2000-11-03. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' 2000-12-16. Leap year correction modified to be symmetrical.
'             Calculation of intDaysDiff simplified.
'             Renamed from YearsDiff() to Years().
' 2000-12-18. Introduced cbytMonthDaysMax.
' 2007-06-22. Version 2. Complete rewrite.
'             Check for month end of February performed with DateAdd()
'             after idea of Markus G. Fischer.

  Dim intDiff   As Integer
  Dim intSign   As Integer
  Dim intYears  As Integer

  ' Find difference in calendar years.
  intYears = DateDiff("yyyy", datDate1, datDate2)
  ' For positive resp. negative intervals, check if the second date
  ' falls before, on, or after the crossing date for a full 12 months period
  ' while at the same time correcting for February 29. of leap years.
  If DateDiff("d", datDate1, datDate2) > 0 Then
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("yyyy", intYears, datDate1), datDate2))
    intDiff = Abs(intSign < 0)
  Else
    intSign = Sgn(DateDiff("d", DateAdd("yyyy", -intYears, datDate2), datDate1))
    If intSign <> 0 Then
      ' Offset negative count of years to continuous sequence if requested.
      intDiff = Abs(booLinear)
    End If
    intDiff = intDiff - Abs(intSign < 0)
  End If

  ' Return count of years as count of full 12 months periods.
  Years = intYears - intDiff

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part to get whether borrower is out of date for PFS, IE check boxes, dates,

You can use following equation on  control source of borrower control to indicate True or False

iif( checkPFS.value = True and CheckIE.value = True ,False,iif(checkPFS.value = True and CheckIE.value = True and PFSDate='' and IEDate='',True, False))